# Downloading Pictures from Azure Blobs into PictureBoxes?

Tags: winforms, azure

I have a Windows Forms Application which accesses folders from my hard drive and using a foreach loop displays 15 photos in 15 pictureboxes with no problems.

I have moved these picture folders into my Azure Storage account and would now like to change my code to access these folders in preparation for final deployment.

Comment: What, exactly, is your question? What folders are you referring to? Are you talking about blob containers? Or some file system somewhere? Please edit your question to be more clear.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can easily load an image from a URL using the Load method of `PictureBox` control. Take a look at the [this MSDN page](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f6ak7was.aspx) for an explanation how the method works. You basically have to do the following:

```
pictureBox.Load("http://urlhere.com/image.jpg");
```

Comment: Thanks for the lead, I'll get to work on it and check back.